# ffmpegを使用して音声のボリューム値をtxt化したい

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

お世話になります。

前提条件
①hlsを使用している
②暗号化している

使用コマンド

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -allowed_extensions ALL -i amovie="abcdef.m3u8,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0
```

環境
OS MacOSX El Capitan
ffmpeg 4.0.2 （brewインストール）
configuration:

```
--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --enable-openssl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree
```

[ffmpeg txt from audio levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056970/ffmpeg-txt-from-audio-levels) を参考にしているのですが、ffprobeに渡すと

```
Filename extension of './encrypt.key' is not a common multimedia extension, blocked for security reasons.
If you wish to override this adjust allowed_extensions, you can set it to 'ALL' to allow all
```

となってしまいます。

ffmpegを使用して音声のボリューム値をtxt化したいのですが、暗号化したhlsを使うとうまくいきません。`-allowed_extensions ALL`をうまく渡すにはどこに記述すべきでしょうか？

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: [エラーメッセージ](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.0.2/libavformat/hls.c#L645-L654)からの推測ですが、HLS/m3u8ファイル記載(？)の暗号化キーファイル(`encrypt.key`)をメディアタイプと判定しようとして失敗しているようです。該当HLSコンテンツはそもそもffmpegで再生(復号)可能ですか？一旦別のメディア形式に変換（＆再エンコードなし）するなどの対処がとれるなら、そのほうが無難かもしれません。

Comment: @yohjp さん　コメントありがとうございます。ffprobeコマンドを使ってdurationを確認したり、ffplayコマンドを使って再生することは可能です。
動画をエンコードする際はcopyを使っているのですが、エンコードしたファイルの音がエンコード前と差がないかを検証したくてボリューム値を取りたいと考えています。